# Sharing a folder with Win 2k3 - Only allows localhost

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have a mostly new install of Windows 2003 Standard Edition SP2, and I'm trying to share a folder on the network.  The instructions here, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324267, describe the steps I took to share the folder.  It's pretty simple.

- Go into the folder properties and enable sharing.
- Make sure the correct users and groups are given permission to access the folder.
- I also unchecked "Allow inheritable permissions from parent to propagate to this object" so I could fine tune the permissions.

Unfortunately I cannot access the share over the network.  It simply says, "Windows cannot find '\192.168.1.10'.  Check the spelling and try again... etc."

When I try to access the share (\192.168.1.10) from the 2k3 server itself, no contents are displayed.  However, when I access \127.0.0.1 everything shows up normally.

What have I done?  Is there a setting somewhere that defines which address the file sharing will use to listen and is it set to localhost?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a very simple solution.  I did not bind the "File and Printer Sharing" to the network interface...

Embarrassing, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Access Based Enumeration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784710(WS.10).aspx) that could do it with a weird mix of permissions. Try turning ABE off and see if that resolves it, if it is on.

Comment: It was actually much simpler than that...

Thanks for the response though! :)